# T-SQL performance issue with bulk insert in millions of data

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, t-sql

I have created a query which is doing a bulk insert of millions of rows of data.
While running this query, I'm getting a temdb memory error.

This is the query:

```
INSERT INTO ods.contact_method (cmeth_cust_id, cmeth_chan_type_id, cmeth_address_id, 
                                cmeth_identifier, cmeth_active, cmeth_review_date, 
                                cmeth_last_validated, cmeth_updatesrc_id, cmeth_updated_date) 
    SELECT 
        custpers_cust_id, 5, ad.adet_id, 
        COALESCE(street3, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(street2, '') + ' ' 
        + COALESCE(housenumber, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(street, ''), 
        CASE custpers_status 
           WHEN 'InActive' THEN 'N' 
           ELSE 'Y' 
        END, 
        Dateadd(year, 2, last_update_date), 
        last_update_date, 1, Getdate() 
    FROM   
        ods.address_detail (nolock) ad 
    JOIN 
        ods.customer_persona (nolock) cp ON cp.custpers_cust_id = ad.adet_updated_by 
    JOIN 
        ods.tempcust_address_insert (nolock)tp ON tp.bvoc = cp.custpers_bvoc_id 
    WHERE   
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM ods.contact_method (nolock) cm 
                    WHERE cm.cmeth_cust_id = cp.custpers_cust_id 
                      AND cm.cmeth_address_id IS NOT NULL
                      AND ad.adet_id = cm.cmeth_address_id)
```

I need help optimizing this query; should I use Left join or not exists condition on millions of data for bulk insert?

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(`right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics)` and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: [`NOT EXISTS` is better than `LEFT JOIN`](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join). How many millions of rows are you talking, a couple of million, or a couple of hundred million? Can you post the execution plan? What indexes do you have on your tables? Also, you may wish to read this - [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).

Comment: This is definitely *NOT* a bulk insert operation. It's a plain old, fully logged INSERT. `NOLOCK` means `Give me dirty data`, not `go fast`. What is the execution plan? What indexes are there?

Comment: Use SSIS to read the data from one end and insert them to the target table on the other end. This will perform a *real* bulk insert, minimally logged operation.

Answer (score -1):

you are getting memory error in temp db can be due to below 2 issues-

1) your query is have performance issue and selecting unnecessary data. - i can not comment on this without knowing table structure, index, fragmentation and size of data. however changing if exists condition to Left join surely help to improve performance -

```
FROM   ods.address_detail (nolock) ad 
   JOIN ods.customer_persona (nolock) cp 
     ON cp.custpers_cust_id = ad.adet_updated_by 
   JOIN ods.tempcust_address_insert (nolock)tp 
     ON tp.bvoc = cp.custpers_bvoc_id          
left join contact_method  cm (nolock)
on  cm.cmeth_cust_id = cp.custpers_cust_id 
AND ad.adet_id = cm.cmeth_address_id
AND cm.cmeth_address_id IS NOT NULL  -- not sure if this condtion is required 
Where cm.cmeth_cust_id is null  -- add all primary key columns of contact_method here
```

2) temp db memory error will also come if you are selecting huge amount of data as compare to temp db size - 
to solve this issue you can use 'top' while inserting the data and run the same query multiple time and left join condition in your insert query will make sure  that no duplicate data is inserted.

```
SELECT  top 1000000   -- this will make sure your are selecting limited data
    custpers_cust_id, 
   5, 
   ad.adet_id, 
   COALESCE(street3, '') + ' ' 
........
```

If this is not a one time activity that your have to write a while loop using @@rowcont value to insert the data -

```
while COUNT( @count>0)
begin

    <your insert statement wiht select top >
    set @count = @@ROWCOUNT     
end
```